# Facebook count likes generated for an external site

Tags: facebook

We have references to other companies on our website and provide the option for people to 'like' them. After a quick skim of the Facebook documentation, I can't work out how to calculate the number of likes our website generates for others so we can measure our effectiveness. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: check this Question's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383032/show-alert-on-a-button-click/7383054#7383054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to "edge.create" and count user likes of any like button on your site.
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get this from the graph api for example https://graph.facebook.com/http://www.google.com there you can find the total number of likes and comments

Answer (score 2):

There is another source (website or something) that have a like button with the same url? if not, you can query link_stat table using FQL to know the number of likes of a url. if yes, I think that the only option is to store the likes count in your website code, in a database or something.