# Show alert on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, embed, alert

I'm using the default Facebook embed code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=176702405718664&amp;xfbml=1"> </script>
<fb:like href="http://domain.com" send="true" width="700" show_faces="false" action="recommend" font=""></fb:like>
```

.. but I'd like to show an alert if the user clicks 'recommend' or 'send' buttons. Please see this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4wB9x/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will have to subscribe to the edge.create event, it gets triggered when user clicks the like button.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
function(response) {
    alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
   }
);
```

// for send you will have to use this

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('message.send',
function(response) {
    alert('You sent the URL: ' + response);
   }
);
```

Comment: Aha! So directly on the page in <script> tags?

Comment: yes, make sure you have included the "all.js" script of facebook js sdk

Comment: yes i see that send button has a diff. event, updated the answer accordingly